# Inner join and delete not working in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `table1` and `table2`. I want to delete from `table1` based on a condition in `table2`.

I have the following mysql query:

```
DELETE FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.col1 = table1.col1
WHERE table2.col2 = '1'
```

This return a syntax error. Is there something wrong with the above syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the table you are deleting from:

```
DELETE table1
    FROM table1 INNER JOIN
         table2
         USING (col1) 
    WHERE table2.col2 = '1';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 'C'
    FROM table2
    WHERE table2.col1 = table1.col1
    AND table2.col2 = '1'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE col1 IN (select col1 from table2 WHERE table2.col2 = '1');
```