# Delete using Select Inner Join from Same Table

Tags: mysql, subquery, inner-join

I am trying to Delete from Table A where the ID exists in a Select Inner Join that includes Table A similar to:

```
Delete from TableA where ID in 
(Select Distinct A.ID from TableA A
Inner Join TableC C
Inner Join TableJ J
Inner Join Table J J2
On J.VendorID=J2.VendordID
and J.Title=J2.Title
and A.C_ID=C.C_ID
and J.ID=A.J_ID
and J2.ID=C.J_ID)
```

The Select works like I want (amazingly) but I keep getting the error

`1093 - You can't specify target table 'TableA' for update in FROM clause`

Which I assume means you can't try to delete from a table that is included in your subquery. Is there anyway to restructure this so I can?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inner join and delete not working in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407767/inner-join-and-delete-not-working-in-mysql)

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47762468/3179169

Comment: @clinomaniac Awesome fix I updated question above feel free of course to provide as full answer I will select it as The Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a subquery.

```
Delete A from TableA A
Inner Join TableC C
Inner Join TableJ J
Inner Join TableJ J2
On J.VendorID = J2.VendordID
and J.Title = J2.Title
and A.C_ID = C.C_ID
and J.ID = A.J_ID
and J2.ID = C.J_ID
```

Comment: I in fact did `Delete A.* from TableA A1` but that works too.